# MapKit annotations imported from MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, nsstring

I've been creating an app that is supposed to show Pins on a Map that are stored in a MySQL Database. I've used JavaScript to convert the Database to JSON then converted the JSON data into NSStrings.

The problem here is I then needed to convert two of these NSStrings into doubles because my Pins need to placed via latitude and longitude, here is my code below that when it builds shows no issues but crashes my simulator and shows up some errors which I shall post directly under my code.

Hazards.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Hazards : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDegrees latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDegrees longitude;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ROUTE;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * ADDRESS;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * LATITUDE;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * LONGITUDE;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * HAZARD;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * RISK;



// Methods
- (id) initWithID: (NSString *) hazardsID andROUTE: (NSString *) hazardsROUTE andADDRESS: (NSString *) hazardsADDRESS andLATITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLATITUDE andLONGITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLONGITUDE andHAZARD: (NSString *) hazardsHAZARD andRISK: (NSString *) hazardsRISK;

@end
```

Hazards.m

```
#import "Hazards.h"

@implementation Hazards
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, ID, ROUTE, ADDRESS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK, latitude, longitude;

- (id) initWithID: (NSString *) hazardsID andROUTE: (NSString *) hazardsROUTE andADDRESS: (NSString *) hazardsADDRESS andLATITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLATITUDE andLONGITUDE: (NSString *) hazardsLONGITUDE andHAZARD: (NSString *) hazardsHAZARD andRISK: (NSString *) hazardsRISK {

    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        ID = hazardsID;
        ROUTE = hazardsROUTE;
        ADDRESS = hazardsADDRESS;
        LATITUDE = hazardsLATITUDE;
        LONGITUDE = hazardsLONGITUDE;
        HAZARD = hazardsHAZARD;
        RISK = hazardsRISK;

        latitude = [hazardsLATITUDE doubleValue]; // convert the string hazardsLatitude to a double here
        longitude = [hazardsLONGITUDE doubleValue]; // convert the string hazardsLongitude to a double here

    }
return self;
}


-(NSString *)title
{
    return self.HAZARD;
}

-(NSString *)subtitle
{
    return self.ADDRESS;
}

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "Hazards.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *json;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *hazardsArray;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

#pragma mark - Methods
-(void) retrieveData;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Hazards.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

// Railway Street Ballymena Coordinates
#define BALLYMENA_LATITUDE 54.857719;
#define BALLYMENA_LONGITUDE -6.280654;

// Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.01f;

#define getDataURL @"www.ryanball.net/royalmail/json.php"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize json, hazardsArray, mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    // Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = BALLYMENA_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = BALLYMENA_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;

    // Set our mapview
    [mapView setRegion:myRegion animated: YES];

    // Annotation
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    Hazards *myAnn;

    // Pin to show Royal Mail Ballymena delivery office
    myAnn = [[Hazards alloc] init];
    location.latitude = BALLYMENA_LATITUDE;
    location.longitude = BALLYMENA_LONGITUDE;
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = @"Royal Mail Ballymena";
    myAnn.subtitle = @"111, Railway Street";
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Methods
-(void) retrieveData {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    // Setup our hazards array
    hazardsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i =0; i < json.count; i++) {

        // Create hazard object
        NSString *hazardsID = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSString *hazardsROUTE = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ROUTE"];
        NSString *hazardsADDRESS = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"ADDRESS"];
        NSString *hazardsLATITUDE = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"LATITUDE"];
        NSString *hazardsLONGITUDE = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"LONGITUDE"];
        NSString *hazardsHAZARD = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"HAZARD"];
        NSString *hazardsRISK = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"RISK"];

        Hazards *myHazards = [[Hazards alloc] initWithID:hazardsID andROUTE:hazardsROUTE andADDRESS:hazardsADDRESS andLATITUDE:hazardsLATITUDE andLONGITUDE:hazardsLONGITUDE andHAZARD:hazardsHAZARD andRISK:hazardsRISK];

        // Add our hazards object to our hazards array
        [hazardsArray addObject:myHazards];
    }
     [self.mapView addAnnotations:hazardsArray];
}

@end
```

Here is the error log I get in the console:

```
2013-04-25 09:04:43.628 RoyalMailApp[6596:c07] -[Hazards setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c63a60
2013-04-25 09:04:43.629 RoyalMailApp[6596:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Hazards setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c63a60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b3c012 0x1458e7e 0x1bc74bd 0x146c7ea 0x1b2bcf9 0x1b2b94e 0x2698 0x47e1c7 0x47e232 0x3cd3d5 0x3cd76f 0x3cd905 0x3d6917 0x39a96c 0x39b94b 0x3accb5 0x3adbeb 0x39f698 0x1a97df9 0x1a97ad0 0x1ab1bf5 0x1ab1962 0x1ae2bb6 0x1ae1f44 0x1ae1e1b 0x39b17a 0x39cffc 0x215d 0x2085 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```